# Get store ID that a page belongs to

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to find out what store a page belongs to in Magento. We currently have along these lines:

```
$cms_pages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
$cms_pages->load();

foreach($cms_pages as $_page) {
    $data = $_page->getData();
}
```

How would I get the store ID for each page?  Ideally I'd like something as simple as `$data->store_id();` but I've not found anything of use yet. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think a page 'belongs' to a store. You can set which store views you want the page to appear though and Magento will display the correct page based on which store the user is looking at. Could you explain further what you are trying to do?

Comment: We're basically trying to create a dropdown for an extension which will allow a user to select a page. The pages listed must only belong to the (previously selected) store. So, I guess what I would be after than is how to find what store views a page belongs to?

Comment: ok, so you just need to list the pages and Magento will figure out which version to use. The trick is to create different versions of the page with the same URL key. Eg. for the homepage: Create a page with URL key: "home" and select the "English" storeview than create another page with "home" URL key and select "French" storeview. Now you can list "home" in your dropdown and Magento will figure out which version to show. I hope this make sense.

Comment: If you have different url keys (why not?) add the store id to your query like this: $collection=Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->setOrder('sortorder', 'asc');

Comment: Ah, ideal. That code snippet was exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Store id to your collection and it will only return the pages you need:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::ap‌​p()->getStore()->getId())
    ->setOrder('sortorder', 'asc');
```